# Zoom Selection to Fit

Tags: excel, vba, zooming

I recently changed my computer and the different screen resolution changed my Excel dashboard to not fit into one window.

I had a look into few VBA suggestions, but I cannot find a solution that could apply for multiple worksheets, each having a specific cell range to fit it into one window automatically, and only running once, not continuously.

I have code in my main workbook. I'm struggling to understand if it has to fit through the workbook or as a new module.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Worksheets("Dashboard").Activate
    LoginFlag = False
    Login.Show
End Sub
```

How could I insert a VBA that would auto-size a range selection for specific worksheets that would look as the below?

```vb
Dashboard.Range("A1:AD36").Select
ActiveWindow.Zoom = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully I understood your question. I think the code below should help you.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
 Dim s1 As Worksheet
 Set s1 = Worksheets("Dashboard")
 Dim s2 As Sheet2
 Set s2 = Sheet2
 s1.Activate
 s1.Range("C1:D8").Select
 ActiveWindow.Zoom = True
 s2.Activate
 s2.Range("A1:B10").Select
 ActiveWindow.Zoom = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much RCL, would you know how to fit your coding proposal into the existing workbook VBA I have?

Comment: Hi I have updated the answer. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Hi, it is more how would you fit the coding with Worksheets("Dashboard").Activate
LoginFlag = False
Login.Show
into the VBA code you are proposing, should this occurs after the login, or before the login, would the user as well see the update of the worksheets size, or is it into the background?

Comment: That would be up to you. You can do it before or after the login form appears. If you don't want to the user to see the changes in the background I suggest you use `Application.screenupdating = false`. I suggest you test it and see what you prefer but what you prefer might be different to what the user prefer. Also don't forget to set the `Application.screenupdating` back to true once the background work is done.

Comment: it worked perfectly, thanks a lot for your prompt help RCL.